# Menschen vs Leute

Tags: word-usage, usage

Is the same to say *Menschen* and *Leute*? When are they exchangeable? I've heard that if you know the people you use one of this words, but I don't know which. (And I don't know if what I've heard is true either.)

Comment: Could you give an example of what you have in mind? _Menschen_ and _Leute_ isn’t always exchangeable; in fact, I’d say it is rather the minority of cases where it is.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1639, http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4386; see in particular [this comment](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1639#comment3877_1640) (though I don’t agree with it).

Comment: It's nonsense that you need to know people to call them "Leute". Prove: "die feinen Leute" - "das vergessen die Leute nicht" - "kleine/große Leute" - "was werden die Leute dazu sagen" - "unter die Leute kommen" - "etwas unter die Leute bringen". However, it may refer to people you know very well, i.e. family (meine Leute gehen mir auf den Nerv), colleagues or friends (Leute, hört mal), employees (fähige, gute Leute; gutes Verhältnis zu seinen Leuten)

Comment: @c.p.: Your teacher is right. The doctor could (but must not) say *Leute* if he speaks about the people he has seen. But it's not appropriate, if e.g. the health insurance reports its statistics

Comment: Menschenrechte gibt es nicht mit Leuten.

Comment: 'Menschen' rather means humans than people. People translates to 'Leute' in most cases

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The way I always explain it is that **Menschen** is shifted toward **human** while **Leute** is shifted toward a colloquial use of **people**... maybe a bit like **folk(s)**. Consequently, **Leute** is also fine if you're going down the derogatory route but it is not part of the word per se.

Let's look at some examples now.
If you talk about your last night out and you describe the bar you'd use Leute.

> Da waren viele merkwürdige Leute.

**Menschen** would sound weird because it has this emphasis on **human**, which is totally superfluous.
On the other hand, if you talk about people suffering from a disease it makes sense to bring the human side in there. **Leute** would sound too casual.

> Menschen, die an dieser Krankheit leiden...

Also here, **Leute** would be wrong

> Irgendwann leben Menschen auf dem Mars.

The point is that humans live there... not just some random dudes.
There is an overlap in the middle where either version is fine. A politician could use either one in a speech.

> Die Menschen/Leute wollen wissen, wie es weiter geht.

One big grammatical difference is that **Menschen** has a singular whereas **Leute** hasn't. 
And lastly, it has been pointed out in comments that there is a fair number of idioms using **Leute**.

So... use **Menschen** if the human aspect bears relevance. Use **Leute** if you are talking casually and you just mean folks, guys, people, etc.

Answer (score 1):

IMO *Leute* is usually in the context of local neighborhood where you can define that *local* on your own. That's why it sounds **a bit more** intimate and hence also used to emphasize sympathy or familiarness when speaking about those persons, even when you don't know them personally.

*Menschen* is the more general meaning, just like *the individuals* or *human beings*.

---

There is a wide overlapping set where you can say *Leute* and *Menschen*. But if you need to be informal, only use *Menschen*, like in `Der erste Mensch im All`. If you're in a local situation, rather use *Leute*, like in `Alle kleinen und großen Leute bitte mal hier rüber kommen!` or `Was sollen denn die Leute von dir denken?!`.