# What word to use to indicate number of people

Tags: numbers

When you are in a situation where someone asks how many people are there, do you use Leute, Personen, or Menschen?

Comment: Nothing, just the question word "wieviele", the same way you don't ask "welcher Mensch" but most often "wer?"

Comment: In other words, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @vectory, the question is quite clear. By the way: _wieviel_ is not a question word. See https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/wie_viel.shtml.

Comment: @BjornFriedrich, then, do you capitalize Viele as a noun? No. Then it must be an interrogative pronoun of sorts.

Comment: @vectory, wie kommen Sie vom Thema Zusammen- oder Getrenntschreibung (*wieviele* versus *wie viele*) aufs Thema Groß- oder Kleinschreibung von *viele*?

Comment: Duden-Regel D77 stellt frei, ob substantiviert werden soll, geht in der Regel aber nicht davon aus. Ob eine andere Regel dagegen spricht, konnte ich jetzt nicht sehen. Nun fehlt der Frage "wie viele kommen?" aber das Subjekt; andererseits paart sich *wie* in der Regel nicht mit Nomen. Das hat also alles weder Hand noch Fuß. Der alten Rechtschreibung nach wurde "wieviele" übrigens zusammengeschrieben. Wieso nun nicht mehr, steht in deinem Link leider nicht genau beschrieben.

Comment: Although it's not a duplicate, here there are some answers https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7648/menschen-vs-leute?r=SearchResults&s=1|68.2867

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mostly a fact of the situation.

If you want to ask how many people fit into a car (German: ***Personen***kraftwagen) or into a cabin of an elevator (There is normally a label inside an elevator on which the capacity is declared in *Personen*).

So, as of my understanding it corresponds to a manageable amount of people.

As stated in the  [answer to the other post](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7653/40504), *Menschen* is more refenced to bigger amounts like the population of a city, a country (or even smaller of a apartment building)
Another example would be:

> Das Fußballstadion fasst bis zu 60000 Menschen.

I normally use *Leute* only for pretty undefined amounts of people:

> Gleich nach Eröffnung haben die Leute das Angebotsregal geplündert.

In response to this you can ask:

> Na wie viele kamen denn?

Without using any nouns.

In many situations you may even use synonyms that define the people better like *Kunden* (customers), *Zuschauer* (viewer) or *Mitarbeiter* (employees).

Comment: I totally agree that Leute is, you might say, an indefinite uncount noun. As a count noun it very severly lacks the singular--which alas never stopped anyone from using it as a count noun, even nonstandard singular "Leut"

Comment: And I'd add that it might be informative to compare *Leute* << PIE \*Hlewdh- "man, people", "to grow" with *Laie*, *lay people* << PIE \*leHwos "people (under arms") < \*leh2- "military action" via Lithurgical Latin in contrast to the clergy people (quotes taken from en.wiktionary). Admittedly, there is not much to go on, phonologically: really just one shared *L*; But keep in mind the supposed pre-historic three-partition of responsibilities into laborours, warriors and priests (to which a fourth could be added). I mean, if there is doubt how derogative *Leute* really is and in which context.

Comment: Some would say that my comparison was "unlauter", but *Leute* really does mean commoners, though by and large not peasants, plebs, or even lewd folks. This shouldn't *verleiten* to jump to conclusions, because it's so sketchy that I don't even know how to turn it into a proper question. The call for action about this answer is obviously requesting a comment about the register and subtone of the word. Maybe it's often indefinite, because it wouldn't be proper to address anyone directly with it?

Answer (score 3):

All three are acceptable. For me, it's a matter of style which word you use. Therefore, the following is *my opinion*.

Most neutral is certainly

> - Wie viele *Leute* sind da?
>     
>     <sup>(How many *people* are there?)</sup>

A bit more formal is

> - Wie viele *Personen* sind anwesend?
>     
>     <sup>(How many *persons* are present?)</sup>

Lowest in my style ranking is

> - Wie viele *Menschen* sind da?
>     
>     <sup>(How many *humans* are there?)</sup>

because *Menschen* doesn't actually fit, except in a centext where the distinction between humans and other species is relevant. More about the *Menschen–Leute* distinction can be found in [another posting](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7648/menschen-vs-leute) on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Für die Abwertung meiner Antwort bitte ich um eine Erklärung.

Comment: I would tend to say *Menschen* if the number is *really* large - a demonstration with 50.000 people, a carnival parade with 2 millions - apart from that, I agree with your answer.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf, good point. Thank you.

Comment: I did not downvote but the paragraph about Menschen is quite wonky

Comment: I had downvoted (expecting it to be outweight by others) because it is missing a note about the possibility to use neither, as per my comments.

Answer (score 2):

"Menschen" als Wort für Menschen, wenn es um deren Menge geht, ist nach traditionellem Sprachempfinden eigentlich immer ein faux pas.

"Menschen" sollte man für Menschen nur verwenden, wenn es der Differenzierung zwischen Menschen und anderen Organismen geht:

> Bei der Viehauktion im Stadion befanden sich 700 Menschen und 300 Rinder.

Ansonsten aber sollte man immer versuchen, die Menschen mit einem geeigneten spezifischen Ausdruck zu bezeichnen:

> Die Viehauktion am Samstag hatte 700 Besucher.
>
> Am Strand drängelten sich tausende Urlauber.
>
> Dutzende Kunden haben sich über die verzögerte Lieferung beschwert.
>
> Über 70 Gäste kamen zu Meikes Geburtstagsparty.

Wenn kein geeigneter spezifischer Ausdruck zu finden ist, verwendet man "Personen":

> 700 Personen haben sich zum Schwimmkurs angemeldet.

Der Grund ist, dass für diese Personen ein gängiges spezifisches Wort kaum zu finden ist. "Schwimmkursteilnehmer" oder "Schwimmwillige" wären als Neubildungen zu ungewöhnlich, würden also den Kommunikationsfluss unnötig aufhalten.

Ist die Personengruppe auf andere Weise von einer allgemeinen, undefinierten Menschenmenge abgehoben, nimmt man auch gerne die Bezeichnung für diese Untergruppe, selbst wenn es für die Satzaussage irrelevant ist:

> 150 Schülerinnen und Schüler haben sich zum Computerkurs angemeldet.

(In diesem Beispiel ist es für den Computerkurs nicht entscheidend, dass es Schülerinnenn und Schüler sind; es könnte jedermann sein; jedoch wurde der Kurs eben speziell bei Schülern an einer Schule bekanntgemacht, und so sind es in der Praxis eben Schülerinnen und Schüler, die sich anmelden.)

Statt "Personen" kann man auch "Leute" nehmen, doch ist dies nur in formloser mündlicher Kommunikation angemessen, nicht in stilistisch sauberer schriftlicher.

> Na, wie viel Leute sind denn zum Theaterabend gestern gekommen?

---

***Aus aktuellem Anlass:***

Der Deutschlandfunk meldet in seinen Radionachrichten am heutigen 8. November 2019:

> *Aus einem Bergwerg in Sachsen-Anhalt wurden nach einer Verpuffung 30 Menschen geborgen.

Tja. So ist das. Alles geht den Bach hinunter. Nicht mal der Deutschlandfunk bekommt stilistisch saubere Nachrichtentexte mehr hin. - Meine spontante Reaktion auf solche Sätze: "30 Menschen... und wie viele Tiere?"

Bessere Formulierung:

> Aus einem Bergwerk in Sachsen-Anhalt wurden nach einer Verpuffung 30 Bergleute [oder wahlweise: Personen, Mitarbeiter, Kumpel] geborgen.

Comment: 1. Bei Kursen paßt *Teilnehmer*. 2. Der scheinbare Fauxpas des Deutschlandfunks geht auf das journalistische Bedürfnis zurück, nicht zweimal dasselbe Nomen zu verwenden: in der Überschrift [des Artikels](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/grube-teutschenthal-mehr-als-30-personen-nach-verpuffung.2932.de.html?drn:news_id=1067868) steht *Personen*, im Text außerdem noch *Beschäftigte*.

Comment: @DavidVogt  Deine Anmerkung, dass man einfach *150 Teilnehmer haben sich zum Schwimmkurs angemeldet* sagen könnte: Ja, das stimmt im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch wohl. Allerdings neigen Anbieter solcher Kurse dazu, als *Teilnehmer* nur solche Personen zu bezeichnen, die auch wirklich teilnehmen (also während der Kurs schon läuft), und nicht Leute, die sich (bisher nur) angemeldet haben. Wer Kurse organisiert, weiß, dass das ein erheblicher Unterschied sein kann: *Wir hatten 50 Anmeldungen... aber am Ende nur zehn Teilnehmer.*

Comment: *Mensch* erscheint mir kaum unangebracht, insofern es das ehemals nicht wirklich geschlächtige Wort, fortsetzt, welches heute Männer bedeutet; Vgl *Mädchenmannschaft* u.ä. Ob das neben Tier auch im Kontrast zu Unmensch welcher Art auch immer gestanden hätte, kann mit dieser banalen Antwort leider nicht gewürdigt werden. Vgl übrigens Altdeutsch *untere* (schlecht) oder so ähnlich, nicht direkt zu *unter* vergleichbar (was so paradox wirkt, dass ich mich spontan nicht daran erinnern kann, unter welchem Schlagwort das verortet war; Ah jetzt, ja: vgl [*Zier*](https://dwds.de/wb/zieren)).

Comment: Ich wäre mit stilistischen (wie von @Björn Friedrich) und sonstwie wertenden Zuschreibungen vorsichtig. Entsprechend unter Vorbehalt möchte ich meinen, dass bei Unfall- und Katastrophenmeldungen im Sinne eines nicht identifizierten _body counting_ eine Tendenz zu 'Menschen' besteht, vgl. _Menschen kamen nicht zu Schaden (aber es gab Sachschäden)._ Wenn von 'Personen' als Unfallopfern die Rede ist, impliziert das für mich eine mehr oder weniger vage 'Identifizierbarkeit'. - Den Beispielen hier stimme ich zu.